# Azure function: AttributeError: 'SubscriptionClient' object has no attribute 'subscriptions'

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I'm using Azure function app, durable function for listing the subscriptions and go through each sub to do some process. My code was working fine until a few days ago that it stopped to work by giving this error:

```
AttributeError: 'SubscriptionClient' object has no attribute 'subscriptions'

    Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 405, in _handle__invocation_request
    invocation_id, fi_context, fi.func, args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
      result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 612, in _run_sync_func
      func)(params)
    File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
      result = function(**args)

    File "/home/site/wwwroot/Upgrade/__init__.py", line 38, in main
      for sub in sub_client.subscriptions.list():
    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters, FunctionInvocationContext context) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs:line 96
    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionInvokerBase.cs:line 82
    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionGenerator.Coerce[T](Task`1 src) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionGenerator.cs:line 225
    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(Object instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:line 52
```

I couldn't find out what it is missing.

Here is my code:

init.py

```
import logging

import subprocess
import json
import os
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.containerservice.models import (ManagedClusterAgentPoolProfile, ManagedCluster)

def main(env: str) -> str:
    logging.info('Python aks-upgrade function processed a request.')
    #print("Environment:", env)
    if env:
      try:
        credential = ClientSecretCredential(
          tenant_id='mytenantid',
          client_id = os.environ["function_client_id"],  
          client_secret= os.environ["function_client_secret"]
        )
        
        sub_client = SubscriptionClient(credential=credential)
      except:
        print("An exception occurred")
        #sub_client.subscriptions.list()
      print("Listing Subscriptions....")
      for sub in sub_client.subscriptions.list():   
            print("Sub_Name:", sub.display_name, "Environment:", env)
```

requirements.txt

```
azure-functions
azure-functions-durable

azure-cli
azure-identity
azure-mgmt-containerservice~=16.1.0
azure-mgmt-subscription
azure-mgmt-resource==19.0.0
requests~=2.25.1
```

I have created an application with service principal that has Reader access plus some access to AKS, client_id and client_secret is generated under this app.

I would appreciate if someone can help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just trying to use SubscriptionClient for the first time and was running into this same issue, so I'm glad it wasn't just me.

I did find that they release a new version of the module on 2021-11-25, (see the release notes here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/releases/tag/azure-mgmt-subscription_2.0.0) and it lists a breaking change of "Removed operation group SubscriptionsOperations". The documentation doesn't seem to reflect this, and it's not clear what you're supposed to do instead to list all subscriptions.

I got it working by pinning azure-mgmt-subscription to 1.0.0.